# Can I write that I had a phobia in my personal statement?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, academic-life, statement-of-purpose

I am writing a personal statement for a Ph.D. position. I had phobias of animals earlier which I overcame during my in-vivo lab experiments (for which I am really proud of). Do you think its a good idea to include that I overcame my phobia by myself?

Comment: Could you explain the relevance to the position you're applying for?

Comment: @user2768-Because the Ph.D. position will have lots of animals studies

Comment: Perhaps edit to add that (crucial) detail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a judgement call. On the one hand, if you are sure it is no longer relevant, then mentioning it could be a problem since some would doubt you are cured, I think.

On the other hand, it shows personal growth. Congratulations.

But having grown as a person may not be as relevant to future research as you think. At least in the minds of others.

On balance, it seems best to *not* discuss it in written materials. If it comes up in an interview, it is again a judgement call whether it is wise to mention it. But, at that point, you will have more information on which to make the judgement.

Answer (score 7):

A personal statement is a story/pitch that describes/sells your suitability for a position. Your historic phobia of animals might be a starting point for your story. Overcoming that phobia showcases part of your personality.

> Do you think its a good idea to include that I overcame my phobia by myself?

I don't think overcoming your phobia is the key message, I think how that fits into the broader story is. Try writing a story that starts from your phobia and concludes with your application. See if that story can be worked into a personal statement you're proud of.

---

Buffy [mentions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/154674/22768) the possibility that hiring someone with a historic phobia of animals might be a red flag for a position with animal studies. I agree (and up voted), but I think it depends on the broader narrative.

Comment: Thanks. I decided not to include it